# Geth Error: Cannot access contractAddress from the transaction receipt

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, bytecode

I am trying to instantiate contracts via the geth console.

Here are the instructions I am running:

```
var bytecode = "0x6003600501600202600055"
var createTx = eth.sendTransaction({ from: eth.accounts[0], data: bytecode })
var created = eth.getTransactionReceipt(createTx).contractAddress
```

When I run the last line, I get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot access member 'contractAddress' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

I would appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction receipt is null, that's the reason you‘re getting `cannot access member of null`.

You have to wait until the transaction is included in a block. Then you will have the receipt. And if you had an create transaction (to = 0x0), then contractAddress will be available in the transaction receipt.